# How can i extract data from response (socket)

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

i need some help for extract data from response socket. Precisely the output of the Trace() in the onResponse function.

```
var socket:Socket = new Socket();
var codehtml:String = "test";

function onConnect(e:Event):void {
    socket.writeUTFBytes("GET / HTTP/1.1\n");
    socket.writeUTFBytes("Host: 192.168.1.2\n");
    socket.writeUTFBytes("\n");
}


function onResponse(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    if (socket.bytesAvailable>0) {
        var tmpcode:String = socket.readUTFBytes(socket.bytesAvailable);
        trace(tmpcode);
    }
}

socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onResponse);
socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecError);

socket.connect("www.google.fr", 80);
```

Comment: What error do you get? What is the problem?

Comment: i don't know how to use my var "tmpcode" out of my function onResponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with sockets is that the information can be too big for a single packet. So you can receive half of the message, and then receive the rest of it.

Commonly this is handled with a 'EOF' (end of file) delimiter - a single special character that will match the ending of the message. For example you can receive those two packets:

1. `<start><body>some text`
2. `</body></start>$`

This should be a regular xml data, but you won't be able to get it from the first packet only. So you need to wait for everything to come. But how can you know that it happened? By waiting for this special `$` sign.

This is needed because sometimes the info is not enough to be casted to something readable. Here's a simple solution:

```
const EOL_DELIMITER:String = '$';
var _buffer:String = "";

_socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onSocketData);

function onSocketData(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var data:String = _socket.readUTFBytes(_socket.bytesAvailable);
    _buffer += data; // add everything to a buffer that will store all info until now

    var msg:String;
    var index:int;

    // this will search for the delimeter
    // as long as there is one - there is a message
    // it's in a loop as there might be several messages in one packet
    // if there is no message, this loop will fail and only the buffer will get filled
    while((index = _buffer.indexOf(EOL_DELIMITER)) > -1)
    {
        msg = _buffer.substring(0, index);
        _buffer = _buffer.substring(index + 1); // clear the message from the buffer

        // new message has arrived -> msg var
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!